# Android studio : FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

while I testing my app, I get the following error in the Android-Studio-logcat:

before getting this error, I was clicked on `setPositiveButton` of alert Dialog Button name is **"EMAIL ME"** with **empty EditText.**

**and then I got Unfortunately twist has stopped.**
please I need help!!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.testing.twist, PID: 30072
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown
        Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.1:307)
    at com.testing.twist.login.beginforgotpasswd(login.java:141)
    at com.testing.twist.login.access$400(login.java:26)
    at com.testing.twist.login$4.onClick(login.java:119)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

here is some code of my login.java file

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText Email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button btn_login;
    private TextView tv_signup;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private TextView tv_forgotpasswd_l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email_l);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_passwd_l);
        btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_l);
        tv_signup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_sign_up);
        tv_forgotpasswd_l = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_f_passwd);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validate(Email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        tv_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this,Register.class));
            }
        });

        // Login button hide

        Email.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
        password.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);

        // recover pass textview click
        tv_forgotpasswd_l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showForgotpasswdDialog();
            }
        });

    }
    // Alert Dialog
    private void showForgotpasswdDialog()
    {
        //Dialog Box code
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Forgot your password?");
        //set linear layout
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(30,30,30,30);
        Email.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        //view to set an dialog
        final EditText Email = new EditText(this);
        Email.setHint("Email");
        Email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        //text view
        linearLayout.addView(Email);
        builder.setView(linearLayout);
        //text style

        // Text view
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTextSize(14);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("black"));
        tv.setText("Unfortunately, if you have never given us your email, we will not be able to reset your password.");
        tv.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        linearLayout.addView(tv);
        builder.setView(linearLayout);

        //buttons for EMAIL ME
        builder.setPositiveButton("EMAIL ME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //input email
                String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
                beginforgotpasswd(email);
            }
        });
        //buttons for CANCEL
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                // dismiss dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ///show dialog
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void beginforgotpasswd(String email)
    {
        firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Email sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(login.this,"Failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //get and show proper error message
                Toast.makeText(login.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    private TextWatcher loginTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String emailInput = Email.getText().toString().trim();
            String passwdInput = password.getText().toString().trim();

            btn_login.setEnabled(!emailInput.isEmpty() && !passwdInput.isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };



    private void validate(String usremail, String usrpassword){


        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usremail,usrpassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //Toast.makeText(login.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkEmailVerification();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkEmailVerification()
    {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Boolean emailflag = firebaseUser.isEmailVerified();

        if(emailflag)
        {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(login.this,MainActivity.class));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Verify your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for advice on the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. You've stated you have an empty `EditText`, is this correct?

Comment: yeah, I want advice, when I clicked on "EMAIL ME" button with an empty Email/(EditText) that time app should not get stopped. in that time I want to show an message like "please enter your email" etc  @the.Doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail` requires that the email you're sending the forgot password email to is not empty. Before calling the function check if the email is not empty.

```java
private void beginforgotpasswd(String email)
    {
        if(email.isEmpty()) {
          // display toast
        } else {
          firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Email sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(login.this,"Failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //get and show proper error message
                Toast.makeText(login.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, email was empty. what should I do if email is empty and i clicked on "EMAIL ME" my app get unfortunately stopped. @EraftYps

Comment: In the `beginforgotpasswd()` function check if the email is empty `if (email.isEmpty())` display a toast that the email should't be empty. In the else block you can call the `firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail`

Comment: I do but got still error, can u put some code where should I put those if else conditions  maybe I do mistakes @EraftYps

Comment: thank you so much, the error is gone @EraftYps one more question in this scenario can I add TextWatcher instead of toast?